# Pyhook and pywin32 modules on 64 bit

Tags: python, pyhook, pywin

I have been trying to install pyhook and pywin32 on my 64 bit windows 7 for python 3.5. I cannot seem to find the correct files, as any that i try either do not work, or work only on 32 bit. Does anyone have a link to recent versions that would work on windows 7 64 bit.

Cheers